# Should questions about model releases/permissions/commercial use be off topic?

Tags: discussion

It's not a big problem but we regularly get questions about the various possibly commercial uses of photos of people and places without a legal agreement in place to which the answer can almost always be summarised as 'every country is different so check with your local lawyer' and thus should be closed as 'primarily opinion based'.

[Photos of people on an ad supported website](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/52170/photos-of-people-on-an-ad-supported-website/52182#52182)
[Is it legal to use a photo taken on private property](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/41361/is-there-any-situation-where-it-is-legal-to-post-a-photo-taken-in-private-proper/41502#41502)
[Can I publish photos taken in public legally](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1736/can-i-publish-photos-taken-in-public-legally)

I usually point them at my old question: [When Do You Need a Model Release](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/29181/when-do-you-need-a-model-release) but that has problems in that it is essentially an open ended list question and thus equally poor.

Even [this otherwise excellent question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12195/what-legal-restrictions-to-photography-are-there-in-european-countries?rq=1) is still essentially a 'list' question.

Is it worth adding something to the FAQ (or some sort of wiki item) about this sort of question and pointing askers to it when closing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Questions about the \*business\* of photography: on or off-topic?](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/614/questions-about-the-business-of-photography-on-or-off-topic)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is a duplicate as suggested by Esa, but the short answer to your question is no. The point of the site is to compile photographic knowledge into one place and it's not unreasonable to answer a question with your own information and note that consulting a lawyer is still a wise idea. Laws vary, sure, but there is commonality and if we want to be a one stop shop for photography then these questions can come up and should be answerable.

Answer (score 3):

No, these questions are not at all opinion based.  There is generally a right answer.  We may not be in a position to answer it in some cases, but there is generally an answer.  They may be too broad if they don't really narrow down the location and situation and we may not have anyone qualified to answer them, but opinion based isn't the reason to close.